# zIndex issue on regular shape for ol3-google-maps

Tags: ol3-google-maps

I just want to use some `ol.style.RegularShape` but they actually don't fit the right z-index. Indeed if I `setAt()` the layer to 0 (zero), I see only the shapes but not the map (the actual google layer). In the other hand, If I set to 1 I only see map.

note: `ol.style.Circle` shape works perfectly.

Any advise to how to use RegularShape are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegularShape is not currently supported by OL3-Google-Maps. There's nothing preventing it from being developed as far as I know, but it needs to be developed. Feel free to open an issue on the library's issues page: https://github.com/mapgears/ol3-google-maps/issues/

EDIT: It is now supported as of version 0.8.0